# JAXB marshall class with only one attribute without intermediate element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I have the following class:

```
class A {
  Map<String, String> mapping;

  public A() {...}

  private Map<String, String> getMapping() {...};
  private void setMapping(Map<String, String> mapping) { ... };
}
```

I need to be able to serialize/deserialize this class in XML with the following representation:

```
<a>
  <entry key="foo" value="bar"/>
  <entry key="xbaz" value="xklux"/>
</a>
```

We use **jaxb-intros** to configure JAXB for these classes, and I have the following configuration:

```
<Class name="A">
  <XmlRootElement name="a"/>
    <Method name="getMapping">
      <XmlElement name="mapping"/>
      <XmlJavaTypeAdapter value="MappingAdapter"/>
    </XmlMethod>
</Class>
```

Which works but produces:

```
<a>
    <mapping>
        <entry key="test" value="a"/>
        <entry key="mdx.foo" value="bar"/>
    </mapping>
</a>
```

My question is: how do I get rid of this awful `mapping` element?

I tried removing the `XmlElement` element in my JAXB configuration but then I end up with

```
<a/>
```

JAXB is not even calling the adapter code.

My second attemps is with another adapter, `AAdapter` (supposed to handle directly the `A` object), that I suppose would be configurable this way:

```
<Class name="A">
  <XmlRootElement name="a"/>
    <XmlJavaTypeAdapter value="AAdapter"/>
</Class>
```

But then its `marshal()` method is not called, and I have no error message from JAXB (which might be due to our JAXB configuration which is another story). And I get the following output:

```
<a/>
```

The `AAdapter` should directly produce the `entry` elements if it was called.

I saw multiple related posts on how to remove intermediate markup for **sub** attributes but they seem to be different to my problem since here I want to remove the element for a direct attribute.

So how can I call an adapter for an attribute without putting its result in an element? Or how do I call an adapter directly on the class to serialize?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Edit: based on [this JAXB ticket](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-117) this seem impossible by design, but if anyone has a workaround it would be great.